# How can I run a paged query in EF Core if Skip and Take are always evaluated locally?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API which uses Entity Framework Core (version 2.0.2) to return a paged list of a data model called `PhotoAlbum`. To do this it builds up an `IQueryable<PhotoAlbum>` like this:

```
    var query = _context.PhotoAlbums
        .Include(album => album.SpotlightPhotoView)
        .ApplySecurity(user)
        .ApplyFilter(filter)
        .Sort(sortInfo);
```

Where `ApplySecurity`, `ApplyFilter` and `Sort` are my own extensions which apply two `Where` filters and an `OrderBy` filter respectively. Finally the code uses `Skip` and `Take` to return a specific subset of the matched data.

I was interested to see in my logs the following warnings:

> The LINQ expression '"Take(__p_2)"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>
> The LINQ expression '"Skip(__p_1)"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>
> The LINQ expression '"where [album].Featured"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>
> The LINQ expression '"where (([album].Complete OrElse False) OrElse False)"' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Having read up on these warnings I now know that certain Linq methods in EF Core cannot be converted to SQL. These include aggregation functions like `Sum` and `Count` as well as `Skip` and `Take`.

So my first question is: **What is the recommended solution if you want to achive a paged query? Is a stored procedure the option option?**

My second question is: **Why do I have the warnings around the `Where` clauses?**

To ellaborate on this second question, the code which applies the `[album].Featured` filter looks like this...

```
    query = query.Where(album => album.Featured);
```

The code which applies the `[album].Complete` filter looks like this...

```
    query = query
        .Where(album =>
            album.Complete || filter.IncludeIncomplete
            && album.Published || filter.IncludeUnpublished);
```

...where `filter` is a simple model with a set of boolean properties defining how to filter.

And here's the actual SQL executed according to my logs (with a few columns removed from the `SELECT` for readability):

```
SELECT [album].[AlbumID], [album].[AlbumDate], [album.SpotlightPhotoView].[PhotoViewID]
FROM [PhotoAlbum] AS [album]
LEFT JOIN [PhotoView] AS [album.SpotlightPhotoView] ON [album].[SpotlightPhotoViewID] = [album.SpotlightPhotoView].[PhotoViewID]
WHERE ([album].[Complete] = 1) AND ([album].[Featured] = 1)
ORDER BY [album].[AlbumDate] DESC
```

It seems to have applied the `Featured` and `Complete` filters fine in spite of the warnings.

Comment: Which EF Core version are you using? Earlier EF Core versions didn't implement every LINQ operator and used local evaluation. EF Core 3 disabled this. Have you tried using `Skip()` and `Take()` with a *simple* LINQ query?

Comment: What do `ApplySecurity`, `ApplyFilter` and `Sort` do? What are those filters? If any of them uses an expression that *can't* be converted to SQL, the entire query will have to be evaluated locally. The warning about `where [album].Featured` is very strange too - is this a locally calculated property? That can't be evaluated on the server because the server has no idea what the formula for `Featured` is

Comment: `where (([album].Complete OrElse False) OrElse False)` is *definitely* invalid. There's no `OrElse` in SQL. Why not a simple `Where(album=>albuc.Complete)` ?

Comment: You'll have to post your *actual* entity, context configuration and filtering code. The warnings show that there are several expressions that can't be converted to SQL by any ORM, much less earlier versions of EF Core.

Comment: BTW `These include aggregation functions like Sum and Count as well as Skip and Take.` that's not true for aggregates since [EF Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation), the latest LTS (Long Term Support) version. Are you using an earlier, possibly unsupported version?

Comment: Thank you for all comments. I will check version and update question ASAP.

Comment: BTW I can't reproduce any issues with EF 2.2.6 or EF Core 3 Preview 8 in LinqPad. In both cases the query `Posts.OrderBy(p=>p.PostId).Skip(100).Take(100)` results in `ORDER BY [p].[PostId] OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_0 ROWS ONLY`

Comment: EF version is 2.0.2. Updated the question. Looks like I should first try upgrading to 2.1+. Thanks all for comments. I will also review the code which builds the `Where` clauses and remove anything that can't obviously be translated...

Comment: All the LINQ functions can be translated to SQL. That's one of their primary purposes, and that includes `Skip` and `Take`. Post the code behind `ApplySecurity`, `ApplyFilter`, and `Sort`. You're probably doing something weird there that's causing this issue.

Comment: @getsetcode post your actual code. Upgrading to EF Core 2.1 won't solve the problem, at least one of the expressions in the warnings can't be translated to SQL

Comment: Thanks all. I expect I have enough to work with to fix the issue myself now. I have added the code which applies the `WHERE` clause filters. Maybe the issue is the fact I'm passing a typed model into the predicate when I should be working with primitives. I'll play around and post the solution when I'm done unless someone else gets there first based on my additional info.

Comment: @getsetcode Either upgrade to the latest stable 2.x, or try eliminating these `OrElse False` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the custom methods and their inputs generate expressions that can't be translated to SQL. `where (([album].Complete OrElse False) OrElse False)` definitely can't - there's no `OrElse` in SQL. `OrElse` is a VB.NET keyword.

`where [album].Featured` is another suspicious warning. Filtering by boolean properties is *definitely* supported in all versions. Is `Featured` a calculated property without the proper configuration perhaps?

Apart from that, GROUP BY and aggregate functions were added [in EF Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation), the latest LTS (Long Term Support) version.

Take and Skip definitely work in EF Core 2.2.6 and EF Core 3.0 Preview 8. Trying this query in LinqPad 6 :

```
Posts.OrderBy(p=>p.PostId).Skip(100).Take(100)
```

Generates this SQL query :

```
SELECT [p].[PostId], [p].[BlogId], [p].[Content], [p].[Title]
FROM [Posts] AS [p]
ORDER BY [p].[PostId]
OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_0 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: `OrElse` in LINQ query expression is not the VB keyword, but the expression representing the logical OR (C# `||`, VB `OrElse` operators) - [Expression.OrElse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.orelse?view=netframework-4.8). So it definitely is supported and translated to SQL `OR`. Most likely client eval is a result of a defect/bug in 2.0.2 translation of `Where` conditions in question. And of course client eval of `Where` automatically means client eval of the next operators like `Skip` and `Take`.